# Redacting collections of String efficiently with Google DLP?

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I'm trying to port some DLP/PII de-identifying code that I wrote against the Beta V2 version of the Google DLP Java library classes. It no longer works because the Beta V2 service was retired and the Java API has changed. I've tried to refactor the code based on the new examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data). In the past, I was able to add a collection of `ContentItem` instances to the DLP client request, but now it appears to be limited to one item. Since the Java DLP library wraps an HTTP REST client, I want to make sure that I send data in efficient sizes. I may have hundreds of Strings that I want to send in one request. It's not really feasible to join them into one long String and then split them apart again, and I would prefer to not have to make hundreds of requests. What is the most efficient way of doing this with the new V2 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can batch items together still, just instead use a [ContentItem.Table](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/ContentItem#Table).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It would be nice to add use of ContentItem.Table to the Java examples. It's pretty frustrating trying to go deeper into this API with the sparse Java side documentation. It would also be nice if there would be one single entrypoint to all the Javadocs. I'm starting [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.47.0/index.html), but couldn't find the `ContentItem.Table` class. When I open it in my IDE it seems to be in one of the dependency files. A landing page with links to all Javadoc locations would be great.

Comment: I'll follow up with the folks who create the doc and find out why that javadoc site is so out of date ... it doesn't contain many things and I"m not sure why. I know it's not javadoc, but the source of truth which will always be up to date is at cloud.google.com/dlp

Comment: I just filed a bug for the missing javadoc https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/3293